# Regex. Overlapping groups with capturing

Tags: regex

Given a string `abcde`
I want to get matches like so:
`abc`,`bcd`,`cde`

I have tried this `((.)(?=..))` but it gives me `aaa`,`bbb`,`ccc`

Comment: Use `(?=(\w{3}))` or `(?=(.{3}))`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bFMj0k/1). I doubt your pattern gets you what you say though, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wdr1vl/1) of your regex

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry I miss that I need to use the two last characters as a backreferences to the very first one

Comment: There are no backreferences in the pattern. What do you mean? Please edit the question with more details.

Comment: If you need more help, please let know.